# Java ObjectInputStream (server\client)

Tags: java, objectinputstream

server thread

```
package schatserver;

public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.start();
    } 



 public void run() {
        try {
             ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());
              ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
        container = (Message) inputStream.readObject();  
        .....
        ..... etc
```

and "Message class" contains at both server side and client side

```
public class Message implements Serializable {

private String login;
private String message;
private String[] users;
private Date time;

public Message(String login, String message){ //for client
        this.login = login;
        this.message = message;
        this.time = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    }


 public Message(String login, String message, String[] users){//for server
        this.login = login;
        this.message = message;
        this.time = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        this.users = users;
    }
```

trying sending Object "Message"

```
private static Message message;

public void Connect() {
        try {            
            sock = new Socket(ClientConfig.HOST, ClientConfig.PORT);
            System.out.println("Connected with: " + ClientConfig.HOST);                        
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject(message);
            out.flush();
```

getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: socketchatclient.Message" at this line

```
 container = (Message) inputStream.readObject();
```

can someone explain me how should i send Object Message?

socketchatclient. - it's client  package

Comment: when you call sock.getInputStream... the return value are null?

Comment: ok... you are tried usign wrappers bufferedinputstream/bufferedoutputstream in client&server? (buffer underflow may be?)

Comment: i got java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: packa.Message

Comment: ggrandes all the same even with bufferedoutputstream

Comment: please edit your question and put more-complete code, i don't see relation in classnotfoundexception and nullpointerexception....

Comment: about classnotfound, you have same class "Message" in each side? (client/server) (with externalizable you need a empty constructor, may be with serializable too? (i don't remember)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: socketchatclient.Message

It means you are trying to deserialize a class you don't have.  Most likely the code on your client is different to that on the server and the client has serialized a class it has but unless the server also has this class in the same package it cannot deserialize it.

I suggest you have a common module for serializable objects and both the client and server share to ensure the same classes are available at both ends.

Comment: the package are different, there are two project 1 server side and 1 for client side both have there name of package also Message.java all the same as for client and server

Comment: BTW thx you i realized what the problem was

Comment: @Peter, there's no need for the serializable class to have a public default constructor. This works fine: `class A implements Serializable {private final int n;private A(int n){this.n=n;}public int getN(){return n;}public static A a(int n){return new A(n);}}` (try to serialize `A.a(2)`, deserialize it and read `n`).